# R shinydashboardplus flipbox - how to remove images

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, adminlte

I'd like to have no images for the flipbox, how can I do it?  Tried this (and also setting to NULL):

```
flipBox(
      id = 1, 
      main_img = "",
      header_img = "",
...
```

but instead it gives me this strange image.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and checked the source code of the function. If you copy it into a R script file there is the following code in line 13/14:

```
shiny::tags$img(class = "avatar", 
                src = main_img, 
                alt = "Avatar")
```

Since you cannot control this behavior by a `flipBox()` argument, I defined my own function `flippBox` and deleted the `alt = "Avatar"` argument. I do not see the necessity for this strange pill anyways..